# Manipulate the DOM with function argument

Tags: javascript, function, dom

My goal is for this code to convert the ".textContent" argument to a method. instead its a string.

`const displayMessage = function (selector, method, message) {
document.querySelector(selector) + method + '=' + message;
};

displayMessage('p', '.textContent', 'Hello World');`

Comment: If the second argument really needs to start with a dot, then something like `document.querySelector(selector)[method.substring(1)] = message`. If the dot isn't necessary, then you can remove the `.substring(1)`.

Comment: I tried the code but did work.  my expectation is to change the textContent of the paragraph to the passed in argument every time i call the function

Comment: Yes, it should do just that with the code I've provided. See https://jsfiddle.net/oxgL87ep/1/